# <Table> cell rendering difference between IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with cell coded as follows

```
<td valign="top" class="weekend_days"> 
<div class="block_out"> 
<div class="blockout_text">Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...</div> 
</div> 
</td>
```

In the CSS, I have defined a height for the div as;

```
.block_out {height: 50px;}
```

I have just included the relevant style here.

Now in IE, the cell expands if the content increases, but in Firefox, it does not expand if content is more.

How do I fix this issue (I would not be able to directly remove the height attribute as it is used in multiple places) ?

Comment: Expand vertically or horizontally? Which versions of the browsers are you checking against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`.block_out {min-height: 50px;}`

Example min-height: http://jsfiddle.net/35bsF/2/

Example height: http://jsfiddle.net/35bsF/3/

Comment: I was just playing around with different values for height and found that setting height to auto works fine in Firefox...Is this a good solution AND any reason why the behavior is different in IE Vs Firefox for the height ?

Comment: .block_out {height: auto} would just do the same as don't pass any height values => ( .block_out {} ) and that would be a great solution for your problem. As for question why height gives different behaviors in IE than in Firefox idk.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include table-layout:fixed; in your table-tag:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
```

This will force IE to listen to the dimensions you set. There are quite a few similar posts about this on stackoverflow already.

Uses this solution if you **don't** want your table to expand.

Comment: I want the table to exapnd as per the content...So I am looking for a similar behavior as on IE..